# Подскажите, как связать Entity с несколькими Entities и избежать дублирования

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

Я пишу сайт, вроде реддита, где пользователи выкладывают посты, пользователи оценивают посты.

Вот пример:
[image: Пример поста]

К постам пишут комментарии, которые в свою очередь могут иметь ветки с ответами. Пользователи могут оценить как сами комментарии, так и ответы на них.
Что-то вроде этого:

[image: Пример комментариев]

Получается три Entity:

**Post.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Post {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long postId;

@Column
@NotBlank(message = "Post name cannot be emty or null")
private String postName;

@Column
private Integer voteCount = 0;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId", nullable = false)
private User user;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Comment> comments;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Vote> votes;
```

**Comment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comment", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Subcomment> subcomments;
```

**Subcomment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Subcomment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Comment comment;

    @Column
    private Instant createdDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", nullable = false)
    private User user;
```

Таким образом пользователи оценивают три разных объекта: посты, комментарии и ответы на них. Оценка идет с помощью объекта Vote:

**Vote.java**

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Vote {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long voteId;

    @Column
    private VoteType voteType;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", referencedColumnName = "userId")
    private User user;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Comment comment;


    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "postId", referencedColumnName = "postId")
    private Post post;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Subcomment subcomment;
```

Чтобы не создавать одинаковые Entity Vote для каждого объекта, итого получится три одинаковых Entity с разными названиями, я решил связать Entity Vote с Comment, Post, Subcomment с помощью ManyToOne.  И если, например, пользователь оценивает Post, тогда Vote сохраняется с пустыми полями Subcomment и Comment. Если же оценивает Comment, тогда поля Subcomment и Post сохраняются как null.

Итого, вопрос. Этот способ мне кажется ненормальным, более походящим на костыль. Существует ли более профессиональный и простой способ реализовать данную функциональность?

Простите за длинный вопрос, возможно описал слишком сумбурно. Благодарю за понимание!

Comment: зачем 2 сущности для комментариев? Если у комментария нет связанного (родительского) комментария, то это коммент на весь пост, если есть - то ответ.

Comment: а вот голоса за коммент и голоса за пост могут быть разными голосами и по разному учитываться - то есть они могут быть разными таблицами.

Comment: по-другому как создать подкомменты для комментариев я не знал, поэтому создал вторую таблицу. Т.е. чтобы они не отображались вместе с основными комментами. Как реализовать это без создания второй таблицы? Можно подробнее, пожалуйта?

Comment: Т.е. лучше создать свои голоса для  постов и комментариев и субкомментов? Таким образом будет три Vote entity

Comment: Я думаю, что не надо разделять комментарии и субкоментарии, по мне это одно и то же. А вот голоса я бы разделил на голос за пост и голос за коммент.

Comment: Ок, понял, тогда разделю голоса. А как не создавать две entity комментариев? Можете объяснить подробнее? Просто как потом вызывать их из БД, чтобы ответы относились к конкретному комменту

Comment: `Если у комментария нет связанного (родительского) комментария, то это коммент на весь пост, если есть - то ответ`

Comment: Я это видел, просто как их из БД вызывать потом? Например будет *ngFor в Angular, будут отображаться комменты без родительского коммента. Как теперь заставить ответы отображаться под каждым родительским комментарием?

Comment: А вы сразу все комментарии хотите отрисовать под постом или подгружать динамически? Если сразу, то вам надо загрузить все комментарии, относящиеся к посту, и построить из них дерево комментариев, его и отрисовывать

Comment: Понял, спасибо за подсказку, попробую это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если говорить о костылях и професиональном способе, то можно почитать, скажем, книгу создателя Hibernate - Гэви Кинга - Java Persistemce API и Hiberante. 2 издание 2019 год. Глава 6. Отображение наследования. Или ищите по ключевым словам - @MappedSuperClass, @Inheritance, @DiscriminatorValue. Коротко, суть в том, что Вы делаете в java родительский class Vote и от него наследуете CommenteVote, PostVote, SubcommentPost и с помощью аннотаций указываете как это будет храниться в БД - в одной таблице или в нескольких таблицах. Есть несколько вариантов хранения и у каждого свои достоинства и недостатки. Но во всех вариантах Hibernate берет на себя автоматизацию хранения и доступа к данным.
Например, если надо будет посчитать сколько всего имеется оценок, не надо будет запрашивать три запроса - для количества оценок постов, количества оценок комментарием, количества оценок подкомментариев и потом их складывать, а надо просто запросить количество оценок родительского класса. Короче полиморфизм.