# Использование интерфейса вместо конкретного типа данных в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть 3 таблицы: Item, TypeFloat, TypeString (get'еры set'еры и прочее, не касающееся темы - опущено или упрощено):

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private String name;
}

@Entity
public class TypeString {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private String value;
}

@Entity
public class TypeFloat {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private float value;
}
```

Суть в том что один Item может иметь несколько значений **разных типов**, в примере их 2, на практике их может быть больше *(хотя по коду они будут использоваться как строки почти всегда)*. И ходить по всем таблицам, запрашивая у них все value соответствующие itemId не хотелось бы. Может можно использовать один интерфейс и написать как-то так:

```
public interface DataType {
    String getDataValue();
}

@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    List<DataType> values;
}

@Entity
public class TypeString implements DataType {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private String value;

    public String getDataValue() {
       return value;
   }
}

@Entity
public class TypeFloat implements DataType {
    @Id
    private int itemId;
    private float value;

   public String getDataValue() {
       return String.valueOf(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Страно что вопрос возник в категории-java, потому как вы не спрашиваете ниче нового, а просто делаете МАПУ в которой ключ это-название типа, а значение сам тип. думаю дело даже не в этом, память то не ризиновая, и хранить все это в таком виже я ХЗ

Answer (score 0):

Создатель Hibernate Гэви Кинг, в начале своей книги Java Persistemce API и Hiberante (2 издание 2019 год) пишет о том, что основным достижением Hibernate как раз и является возможность решать задачи аналогичные поставленному в данном вопросе. Основной девиз, который Гэви Кинг добавлял в заголовок своих клаcсов - "Hibernate, Relational Persistence for Idiomatic Java", что можно перевести как "Hibernate - это реляционное хранение под идиоматику java". То-есть программист пишет программу на java используя принципы ООП и проч. (идиоматику java), а Hibernate сам понимает (на основе мапинга) как все раскладывать и брать в таблицах БД. Более подробно я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1198776/220294)